# Groovy compiler does not recognize inner enum/class type

Tags: groovy

MyTestClass1.groovy:

```
class MyTestClass1 {
    public static enum MyEnum { a, b }
    public static class MyInnerClass { void a() {} }
}
```

MyTestClass.groovy:

```
class MyTestClass {
    void test(MyTestClass1 c) {}
    void test2(MyTestClass1.MyEnum c) {}
    void test3(MyTestClass1.MyInnerClass c) {}
}
```

`groovyc -cp . MyTestClass.groovy` won't pass. test2/3 is marked as failure because compiler doesn't know the types.
Is there any trick to get this compiled?

Comment: The example works well in Eclipse with Groovy plugin but the standalone Groovy compiler won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get your same error is to compile `MyTestClass` without having `MyTestClass1` compiled first.  The easiest solution here is just compile all: `groovyc -cp . MyTestClass*.groovy`.

```
$ ls
MyTestClass.groovy  MyTestClass1.groovy
$ groovyc -cp . MyTestClass.groovy  
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
MyTestClass.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class MyTestClass1.MyEnum 
 @ line 4, column 20.
           void test2(MyTestClass1.MyEnum c) {}
                      ^

MyTestClass.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class MyTestClass1.MyInnerClass 
 @ line 5, column 17.
            void test3(MyTestClass1.MyInnerClass c) {}
                   ^

2 errors

$ groovyc -cp . MyTestClass1.groovy
$ groovyc -cp . MyTestClass.groovy 
$ ls
MyTestClass.class  MyTestClass.groovy  MyTestClass1$MyEnum.class  MyTestClass1$MyInnerClass.class  MyTestClass1.class  MyTestClass1.groovy
```

Comment: But I don't know the code dependencies for the files. I thought Groovy should know the dependencies and compile necessary classes first.

Comment: Just compile all (`**/*.groovy`).  Or even better use maven, gradle, make, younameit.